# Rotate xticks in subplots (xticklabels rotation)

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I have a figure with four subplots in it. I want to rotate the `xticks` of all suplots by 45 degrees.

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864719/rotate-x-tick-labels-using-subplots), I believe this can be done with `plt.setp()`.

```py
# Create subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,5), sharex=True, sharey=True)
# Try to rotate the xticks of all axes
plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=45) # Close attempt
# Show
plt.show()
```

[image: close]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cycle through each of your subplots, set it to the current axes, and call `plt.xticks()` on each one.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,5), sharex=True, sharey=True)

for ax in axes.flatten():
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
```

Result:

[image]